# Question regarding period, time and so on

Tags: soft-question

I'm reading a paper regarding the workload of air traffic controller.

In this paper, *P* is a mean task recurrence period per aircraft.
In this context, 'task' mean 'recurring task' which is a repeated activities of controllers (e.g. checking route compliance of traffic)

*t* is a mean required time for controllers to complete this task, and *N* is a number of aircraft in a sector of airspace.

In this case, what *N/P* and *t/P* mean, respectively?

Paper noted that *N/P* is an occurrence rate of this task, and *t/P* is the fraction of total time devoted to recurring task for each aircraft. But I still don't get it... can anyone please explain the logic?

Comment: Why was this down-voted? This is a good question that presents the opportunity for someone to write a nice explanation based on the dimensions of the problem. We should be down-voting questions that show lack of effort, not those that show lack of understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given definitions:

- $N :=$ the number of aircraft
- $t :=$ the mean task duration
- $P :=$ the mean task-recurrence period $\color{red}{\text{per aircraft}}$

Claims:

- $t/P$ is the fraction of total time devoted to each recurring task
  for each aircraft
- $N/P$ is a task occurrence rate

From the above information, it is clear that $P$ is a simple duration (a time quantity), not a rate, and that each aircraft has its own value of $P:$ so, $P$ is actually the mean task-recurrence period **of each aircraft** (nor *per aircraft*).

With this correction,

1. it becomes self-evident that for each aircraft, $t/P$ is indeed the
   fraction of total time devoted to each task.
2. $$\frac NP=\frac{\text{the number of aircraft}}{\text{mean
   task-recurrence period of each aircraft}}\\=\frac{\text{the number
   of aircraft $\times$ number of tasks of each aircraft}}{\text{total
   task-recurrence period of each aircraft}}\\=\frac{\text{total number
   of tasks}}{\text{total task-recurrence period of each aircraft}}$$
   is the task-occurrence rate of each aircraft.